# Asynchronous return from a computed property

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

In a variable which is used for a table view data source array controller, I'm trying to get a value with a asynchronous function:

```
 dynamic var price: Double {
        get {
            if id == "EUR" {
                PriceQuery.shared.loadprice("JPY") { price in
                    return price
                }  
            }
        return 0.0
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error: "unexpected non-void return value in a void function". Although it makes sense that the downer `return 0.0` doesn´t "know" it has to "wait" for the upper asynchronous return, I don´t know how I could solve the problem.

There is already an answer about how to return asynchronously in a function.
But I can't use a completion handler inside a variable, right?

Comment: You can’t. So you’ll have to change how you implement this. But you’re still trying to return a value inside an asynchronous function which can’t be done. The exact scenario is different but the answer is the same. You can’t return a value from a function that uses an async call to get the value.

Comment: I suggest changing your var into a func with a completion handler.

Comment: @Fogmeister Could you give me advice how to implement this?

Comment: @Fogmeister But the Arraycontroller cannot access a function. It needs a variable.

Comment: Then it can’t be asynchronous. You can’t access an asynchronous value synchronously.

Comment: @Fogmeister So this question is not a dublicate. Maybe someone else has an idea for a workaraound.

Comment: The question you asked is a duplicate. Perhaps what you want to ask is how to get that value and put it into your array controller. ... which is an entirely different question.

Comment: See the other question that I just added to the duplicate list.